# How can I get my form which has 2 divs to always center inline on the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my 2 divs which are both inside one form. I would like to display one div per row when the browser is small and expand to 2 columns with each div inside when the screen goes to medium and large size, but always keep both divs perfectly center on the page, here is my html with some css styling:

html

```
<style>
#compare {
    width: fit-content
}
.compare_container {
    display: inline;
}
#id_ingredients {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
.form_card {
    width: fit-content;
}
.compare_cardbody {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
}
.back_button {
    float: left;
}
.back_button_text {
    color: black
}
.back_button_text:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}
h5 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<h4>Please enter in your ingredients:</h4>

<h6>(Seperate each item by comma)</h6>

<br>

<button class="add_item">Add Item</button>


        <div class="container compare_container">

                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 mx-auto">
                            
                            
                            <form action="{% url 'compare_ingredients' %}" method="post" id="compare">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                
                            <div class="col mb-4 mx-auto">
                                <h5>Item 1</h5>
                                <div class="card form_card">
                                    <div class="card-body compare_cardbody">
                                            {{ form1}}
                                            
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        

                            <div class="col mb-4 mx-auto">
                                <h5>Item 2</h5>
                                <div class="card form_card">
                                    <div class="card-body compare_cardbody">
                                            {{ form2 }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                                
                               
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                            
                
                </div>
 
                            
        </div>
```

It currently looks like this but want both forms next to each other when screen is anything above small size :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a div with class row and include both the forms in the div, I have attached the code here, I added a   and two styles row and row after.

#compare {
        width: fit-content
    }
    .compare_container {
        display: inline;
    }
    #id_ingredients {
        text-align: center;
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .form_card {
        width: fit-content;
    }
    .compare_cardbody {
        width: 350px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .back_button {
        float: left;
    }
    .back_button_text {
        color: black
    }
    .back_button_text:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
    }
    h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .row{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .row::after {
        display: table;
        clear: both;
        content: "";
    }

```
<h4>Please enter in your ingredients:</h4>

<h6>(Seperate each item by comma)</h6>

<br>

<button class="add_item">Add Item</button>


        <div class="container compare_container">

                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 mx-auto">
                            
                            
                            <form action="{% url 'compare_ingredients' %}" method="post" id="compare">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col mb-4 mx-auto">
                                    <h5>Item 1</h5>
                                    <div class="card form_card">
                                        <div class="card-body compare_cardbody">
                                            {{ form1}}
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                                <div class="col mb-4 mx-auto">
                                    <h5>Item 2</h5>
                                    <div class="card form_card">
                                        <div class="card-body compare_cardbody">
                                            {{ form2 }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <br>
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                            
                
                </div>
 
                            
        </div>
```

Comment: no this doesn't work , forms are still not centering

Comment: Suggestion : add code fences and the language identifier to highlight the css code and make it more readable.